# how to throw an exeption in method onClick(View v)

Tags: java, android, ioexception

First, I already reviewed some similar questions but the answers didn't help me :(

I trying to program an Android application and this is my problem

```
public void onClick(View v)  {
        String url = Buscar_Random();
        //do something with the variable url
```

I want to call the method `Buscar_Random`, this method throws an `IOException`, so I need to call this exception in the method `onClick`. So i tried this:

```
public void onClick(View v) throws  IOException {
```

But `onClick` is an override method, so I receive this message: `overridden method does not throw 'java.io.IOException'`

I also tried this:

```
    public void onClick(View v)  {
    try {
        String url = Buscar_Random.main();
        //do something with the variable url
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the weirdest part, the app compiles but when i call the method in the app in my Android, the app closes itself (and doesn't even show me the message "Unfortunately blahblah has stopped working"

I also tried to use a `RuntimeException`, but neither worked :(

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your logcat. Probably another exception is being thrown.

Comment: Hi Allan , Please show your error logcat.I suggest you please use Exception e instead of IOException .

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is doing it right.

As for the crash, just because a method doesn't specifically declare that it throws a certain Exception doesn't mean it won't. It could be throwing a NullPointerException, RemoteException, IllegalArgumentException, etc. Also, just because there's no "App has stopped" message doesn't mean the app didn't crash. That dialog isn't always shown.

If you want to just ignore any and all errors from that method (probably a bad idea, since the current crash is probably a bug you need to fix), just catch Exception:

```
try {
    //whatever
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

However, you should really look at the Logcat viewer (bottom toolbar) in Android Studio. Filter by your app only, and set the level to Error and find out why your app is crashing.

Comment: ok, this is an advance. i tried this, the app don't do what is supossed to do but don't closes, thanks!

Comment: Like I said, you really need to look at _why_ another Exception is being thrown.